# eclipse SVN project reconnect after deleting the SVN meta data

Tags: eclipse, svn

I mistakenly disconnected from my eclipse SVN project and also deleted SVN sub-directories meta data. Is there any way to reconnect in to the same SVN project. I tried with "Share Project" option and it seems that only the root folder of the project is having SVN meta data and shows  as connected in eclipse. But all the child folders and files are seems disconnected from SVN. Please let me know, is there any way to reconnect in to SVN in this situation.

Thanks,
Hari

Answer (score 0):

I believe:

```
svn checkout <url> <your_project_dir>
```

in the command line should do the job for you

As it will check it out once again from the svn repo.

Moreover closing+opening(+reloading) eclipse project afterwards should complete the job for eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I would try in eclipse File > import > Project from SVN and you will be prompted to overwrite or not when it finds that the project already exist in your local machine.